# ubuntu power saving turn off screen

Tags: 20.04, power-management

I locked my session and left the desktop computer for several hours.  When I returned the screen was dimmed but still powered on, showing the purple "blank" screen.  How do I configure Ubuntu 20.04 to turn off everything, including the screen, that is not needed for reactivating the system?  Why am I only given the option to blank the screen after a time, not to power it off entirely to save power and wear and tear on the LCD.

Comment: I have the same problem, and unfortunately no solution...